# Android Studio freezes on running app on device in ubuntu 15.04

Tags: android, ubuntu, android-studio, ubuntu-15.04

So, have tried every possible solution related to the problem found on internet but nothing seems to work for me till now.

My ubuntu syslog before the crash:

```
Jul  9 19:51:07 rohanagarwal94 kernel: [ 1823.748990] Purging GPU memory, 69632 bytes freed, 4956160 bytes still pinned.
Jul  9 19:51:14 rohanagarwal94 kernel: [ 1823.749910] java invoked oom-killer: gfp_mask=0x280da, order=0, oom_score_adj=0
Jul  9 19:51:17 rohanagarwal94 kernel: [ 1823.749913] java cpuset=session-c2.scope mems_allowed=0
Jul  9 19:51:17 rohanagarwal94 kernel: [ 1823.749919] CPU: 1 PID: 3566 Comm: java Tainted: P           OE  3.19.0-64-generic #72-Ubuntu
Jul  9 19:51:17 rohanagarwal94 kernel: [ 1823.749921] Hardware name: Hewlett-Packard HP 15 Notebook PC/2212, BIOS F.37 01/21/2015
Jul  9 19:51:17 rohanagarwal94 kernel: [ 1823.749923]  0000000000000000 ffff880157c53a18 ffffffff817cc28b ffff88006ebc13a0
Jul  9 19:51:17 rohanagarwal94 kernel: [ 1823.749926]  0000000000000000 ffff880157c53a98 ffffffff817c9f5a 0000000000000000
Jul  9 19:51:17 rohanagarwal94 kernel: [ 1823.749928]  0000000000000000 0000000000000000 0000000000000000 ffff8801546844b0
Jul  9 19:51:17 rohanagarwal94 kernel: [ 1823.749931] Call Trace:
Jul  9 19:51:17 rohanagarwal94 kernel: [ 1823.749940]  [<ffffffff817cc28b>] dump_stack+0x63/0x81
Jul  9 19:51:17 rohanagarwal94 kernel: [ 1823.749943]  [<ffffffff817c9f5a>] dump_header+0x7f/0x1e7
Jul  9 19:51:17 rohanagarwal94 kernel: [ 1823.749949]  [<ffffffff8118069b>] oom_kill_process+0x22b/0x390
Jul  9 19:51:17 rohanagarwal94 kernel: [ 1823.749954]  [<ffffffff81080f5e>] ? has_capability_noaudit+0x1e/0x30
Jul  9 19:51:17 rohanagarwal94 kernel: [ 1823.749957]  [<ffffffff81180c0d>] out_of_memory+0x24d/0x500
Jul  9 19:51:17 rohanagarwal94 kernel: [ 1823.749961]  [<ffffffff81186bcc>] __alloc_pages_nodemask+0xb2c/0xbc0
Jul  9 19:51:17 rohanagarwal94 kernel: [ 1823.749965]  [<ffffffff811cfa15>] alloc_pages_vma+0x95/0x1b0
Jul  9 19:51:17 rohanagarwal94 kernel: [ 1823.749970]  [<ffffffff811aef0a>] handle_mm_fault+0xdea/0x1030
Jul  9 19:51:17 rohanagarwal94 kernel: [ 1823.749974]  [<ffffffff810ae0f5>] ? update_curr+0x75/0x1a0
Jul  9 19:51:17 rohanagarwal94 kernel: [ 1823.749978]  [<ffffffff81064c2d>] __do_page_fault+0x1dd/0x5b0
Jul  9 19:51:17 rohanagarwal94 kernel: [ 1823.749982]  [<ffffffff810aad5d>] ? set_next_entity+0x9d/0xb0
Jul  9 19:51:17 rohanagarwal94 kernel: [ 1823.749985]  [<ffffffff810b371f>] ? pick_next_task_fair+0x6af/0x8b0
Jul  9 19:51:17 rohanagarwal94 kernel: [ 1823.749988]  [<ffffffff810b371f>] ? pick_next_task_fair+0x6af/0x8b0
Jul  9 19:51:17 rohanagarwal94 kernel: [ 1823.749993]  [<ffffffff81014665>] ? __switch_to+0x1d5/0x610
Jul  9 19:51:17 rohanagarwal94 kernel: [ 1823.749996]  [<ffffffff810a794d>] ? sched_clock_cpu+0x9d/0xb0
Jul  9 19:51:17 rohanagarwal94 kernel: [ 1823.750000]  [<ffffffff817ce524>] ? __schedule+0x394/0x940
Jul  9 19:51:17 rohanagarwal94 kernel: [ 1823.750003]  [<ffffffff81065031>] do_page_fault+0x31/0x70
Jul  9 19:51:17 rohanagarwal94 kernel: [ 1823.750006]  [<ffffffff817d5668>] page_fault+0x28/0x30
Jul  9 19:51:17 rohanagarwal94 kernel: [ 1823.750008] Mem-Info:
Jul  9 19:51:17 rohanagarwal94 kernel: [ 1823.750010] Node 0 DMA per-cpu:
Jul  9 19:51:17 rohanagarwal94 kernel: [ 1823.750012] CPU    0: hi:    0, btch:   1 usd:   0
Jul  9 19:51:17 rohanagarwal94 kernel: [ 1823.750013] CPU    1: hi:    0, btch:   1 usd:   0
Jul  9 19:51:17 rohanagarwal94 kernel: [ 1823.750015] CPU    2: hi:    0, btch:   1 usd:   0
Jul  9 19:51:17 rohanagarwal94 kernel: [ 1823.750016] CPU    3: hi:    0, btch:   1 usd:   0
Jul  9 19:54:03 rohanagarwal94 rsyslogd: [origin software="rsyslogd" swVersion="7.4.4" x-pid="689" x-info="http://www.rsyslog.com"] start
```

I was pretty much a Windows user my whole life. So I certainly know very little about ubuntu and its commands. Would appreciate if someone could provide a solution to the problem.

Comment: As a curiosity, what are you system specs?

Comment: -Computer-
Processor  : 4x Intel(R) Core(TM) i3-4010U CPU @ 1.70GHz
Memory  : 3977MB (2039MB used) // this is without android studio on.
      Operating System  : Ubuntu 15.04